# Is a piece of aluminum foil a valid substitute capacitor for a hollow sphere if their surface areas are the same?

Tags: capacitance

I'm using a sphere as half of a virtual capacitor with the other half being the ground. The sphere's radius is .75" and before I buy a professional one I want to make a junk substitute to make sure my calculations are correct. If I use a piece of aluminum foil 4"x1.75" will the capacitance of each be (close to) the same, because they have similar surface areas and the same material?

Comment: "valid susbtitute" <--- substitute for which purpose? **Any** two oppositely chargeable conductors in this world form a "valid" capacitor. What is a "professional hollow sphere"? Why do you need a hollow sphere as a capacitor? I'm a bit confused!

Comment: Why not wrap the foil around a marble or something?

Comment: I don't think that the flat aluminium foil will constitude the same capacity to ground per unit area as the hollow sphere if that is what you are asking.

Comment: please remove the `transformer` tag. your question appears to have nothing to do with transformers.

Answer (score 2):

A spherical shape is not very effective as far as capacitors are concerned.

However for making a low gradient electric field it serves another purpose.

Since you have not specified the shape of your ground nor the gap, we can only assume that capacitance is not a significant part of this experiment but rather insulation properties or the geometry and not the conductor properties or its negligible effect on capacitance.

As a matter of interest for EE grad's here is an excerpt  from Maxwell's treatise on electricity and magnetism for a sphere above a ground plane . Note that the lines of equipotential are most dense near the sphere surface.
[image]
Parallel plates with a small gap naturally gives the highest capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be similar if you are very far away from any grounded surfaces (or surfaces with a high capacitance to ground) in relation to the dimensions of the object. The material is immaterial provided it's a good conductor. And actual finely grained surface area is not that important either- it's more like effective surface area- convolutions are shielded by nearby conductive material.

Any imperfections compared to a perfect sphere should be viewed in that light- crushing the foil over a trackball ball with 0.75" radius with wrinkles of less than 2mm will have very little effect if you are 1m from the ground. For example, the Logitech M570 is 34mm diameter which is about right.

[image]

A flat plate 4" (100mm) long will likely be **much** (like 50x) worse and will vary with orientation.

Comment: This link (sphere at various distances to plane) http://www.electrostatics.org/images/esa_2008_d1.pdf